# symfony/doctrine getOrganisation() on employee returns a string (but I want an object)

Tags: php, orm, symfony1, doctrine

I'm working on a project with symfony 1.4 & doctrine. 1.2

In my schema.yml I defined an employee and an organization entity:

```
employee:
  tableName: employee
  columns:
    id:
      primary: true
      type: integer(8)
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    organization:
      default: NULL
      type: integer
  relations:
    organization:
      onDelete: restrict
      local: organization
      foreign: id
organization:
  tableName: organization
  columns:
    id:
      primary: true
      unique: true
      type: integer
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
  relations:
    employee:
      type: many
      class: employee
      local: id
      foreign: organization
```

I then run the command `symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load`, this (re-)creates the database with tables and php-classes according to the schema.yml.

So when I now do `$employee->getOrganization()` (assuming $employee is of class employee), I expect to get an object of class organization. But I get a string with the content of organization's id field. 
When I try it the other way round: `$organization->getEmployee()` (assuming $organization is of class organization) it returns a Doctrine_Collection with all employees.

How do I `getOrganization()` to return the organization object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because both your local field and relation have the same name ("organization").

It's better to follow the Doctrine naming 'guidelines':

```
employee:
  tableName: employee
  columns:
    id:
      primary: true
      type: integer(8)
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    organisation_id:   # renamed to 'organisation_id'
      default: NULL
      type: integer
  relations:
    Organisation:      # capitalized
      onDelete: restrict
      local: organisation_id #renamed to 'organisation_id'
      foreign: id
```

Now you can get the ID using `$employee->organisation_id` or `$employee->getOrganisationId()`, and the Organisation like `$emplyee->Organisation` or `$employee->getOrganisation()`.

Comment: Don't be misled by Grad's respelling of "organization" as "organisation" (the spelling preferred outside North America) - that's irrelevant.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Haha, ok, but I'm outside NA and prefer the z. :P

Comment: Both spellings are acceptable in the UK, and some authorities (eg Oxford University Press) prefer 'ize'; but most people use 'ise'. In the US, generally speaking, only 'ize' is used, to the degree that many Americans if they see 'ise' assume it is a mistake and want to correct it.

Comment: @van Horck: I just tried to edit & correct a typo in your answer ($emplyee should be $employee). But it told me, edits have to be at least 6 chars (not sure if I know what that means). maybe you could correct it?